# How can I create ggplot2 titles in Japanese?

Tags: r, localization, ggplot2

I am preparing a presentation in Japanese and would like the titles and legend names of my images to be in Japanese. I can get the text to render just fine in RStudio but when the image is rendered the Japanese characters just appear as boxes.

```
x=-10:10
y=x*x
df=data.frame(x,y)
ggplot(df, aes(x,y)) + geom_line() + ggtitle("テスト")
```

[image]

Thank you.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. I have ran your code and the Japanese characters appear at the top of the graph and when the image is saved they remain. Can you give provide an image of the problem?

Comment: Thanks - I wasn't aware that I could upload images. I just uploaded the image that I see. I did a google search for this problem but couldn't find anything relevant.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems that you do something like this. I am using Mac, and I initially did not see the letters you specified in `ggplot` graph. But the following code is printing the letters.

```
theme_set(theme_gray(base_size=12, base_family="HiraKakuProN-W3"))

ggplot(df, aes(x,y)) + 
geom_line() +
ggtitle("テスト")
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! That works. Can you tell me how to set the theme back to the default?

Comment: @Ari It seems that you do the following. `theme_set(theme_gray(base_size=12, base_family=""))`. I never created ggplot in Japanese before. Good to know how you draw graphs in other languages.