# Unicode characters in ggplot legend

Tags: r, unicode, ggplot2, legend

I am trying to plot some graph using ggplot2 in R and label the legends using unicode characters such as Japanese. The following is my code:

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes(x=mpg, y=wt, colour = 'ああ')) + geom_line()
```

But I end up getting the following plot:
[image]

The legend is not displayed properly. Could anyone tell me how to fix this? Thank you so much!!

Comment: I wonder if [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26794142/how-can-i-create-ggplot2-titles-in-japanese/26794224#26794224) helps you.

Comment: `ggplot(mtcars, aes(x=mpg, y=wt, colour = 'ああ')) + geom_line() + scale_color_discrete(labels = 'ああ')` works, but I dunno why the initial try fails. (Fails = "<U+3042><U+3042>", I'm on Windows 7 x64 (build 7601) with LC_COLLATE=German_Germany.1252 ).

Comment: Same here (in UK) - i get `<U+3042>` as well.

Comment: If locale is not in UTF-8, I never expect anything to work. This is very hard on Windows, though. Linux is more flexible regarding locales.

Comment: @jazzurro Thank you, that works. The problem is we need to set the font family before using the characters. The following code also works.    `ggplot(mtcars, aes(x=mpg, y=wt, colour = 'ああ')) + geom_line() + theme(text = element_text('HiraKakuProN-W3'))`

Comment: I am glad to hear that. :)

Comment: You may want to leave your code as the answer.