# Typesetting combining Unicode in R plots

Tags: r, unicode, plot, graphics, typesetting

The unicode combining overline character, U+0305 is useful for indicating mathematical terms such as `X̅` for the mean of a random variable X. (Some prefer the appearance of the macron, U+0304 (X̄), but a quick Wikipedia suggests this is imprecise.)

I understand how to enter such a character in R, and

```
cat("X\u0305")
```

correctly produces `X̅`. However, when I attempt to place this character in a `plot(1:10,10:1,main="X\u0305")`

the overline is dramatically offset, as shown [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gSs9h.png). The same issue is present in ggplot, as
  `ggplot(data.frame(x=1:10,y=10:1)) + geom_point(aes(x=x,y=y,color="X\u0305"))`

produces [similar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QcLoM.png) output.

I am running Mac OS X El Capitan, and I encounter this problem in both the Terminal and in RStudio. The similarly tagged question, "[Unicode characters in ggplot legend](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39348634/unicode-characters-in-ggplot-legend)" did not solve my problem.

Comment: Maybe it's a font or OS specific issue. I just checked it on Ubuntu and I get the whole bar covering the x-bar instead of the offset like you have.

Comment: Yes in principle this will work but in practice the font you're using must support it, and whatever API is being used to draw that text must support combining characters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another option would be to use `expression(bar(X))`:

```
ggplot(data.frame(x=1:10,y=10:1)) + 
   geom_point(aes(x=x,y=y,color="Xbar")) +   
   scale_colour_discrete(labels=expression(bar(X)))

plot(1:10,10:1,main=expression(bar(X)))
```

`?plotmath` has more info on the various options for mathematical text using expressions in R.